# How to show my app in `open in` menu of other apps for `pdf` file based of selected pdf file size in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uti

I want to show my app in `open in` menu of other apps(ex: mail app, dropbox, etc) for open in action, I have implemented for importing pdf files from other apps everything is working fine. But my question is how can I add`size restriction` for selected **pdf file** like **photos app**.

**For example:** My app should show in `open in` menu only if selected pdf file size is `less than 5mb`.

In photos apps when selecting **6 images** it shows **many apps** in `open in menu` list. Show below image

[image]

But when selecting **51 images** it shows only **3 apps** in `open in menu`. Show below image

[image]

I think in photos app the apps are filtering based on selected photos `total size`. I want these type of functionality in my app. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a key [`NSExtensionActivationRule`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW10) specified in info-plist, that can allow you to filter out data, check here: [Declaring Supported Data Types for a Share or Action Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8)

Comment: @Adil soomro Thanks for your response, I haven't implemented this an action extension. I just gave supported UTI in my app. Your any may be very helpful when I plan to write this function as an `action extension`.